# Using a delegate on a VC that has not yet been loaded

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am attempting to do something which I thought would be quite simple, but I've been struggling with it. I've done a lot of searching, and nothing I can find is exactly what I'm looking to try and do.

I am attempting to pass a string from one VC, to the next VC and change a label on it using a delegate. The issue I am running into is that for some reason the delegate is showing up as nil. (*I receive this error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*) below are some images of my code to help you understand what I've written

First VC code:

```
    @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let newWorkoutVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewWorkoutVC") as! NewWorkoutVC
    if workoutNameTextField.text != ""{
        let workoutName = workoutNameTextField.text!
        nameDelegate.transferText(name: workoutName) //error appears on this line
        present(newWorkoutVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
    }
}
```

Second VC has the delegate being instantiated in view will appear since that it is supposed to take place when the VC is about to load.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let workoutNameVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WorkoutNameVC") as! WorkoutNameVC
    workoutNameVC.nameDelegate = self
```

here is my extension making the second VC conform to my delegate.

```
extension NewWorkoutVC: WorkoutNameDelegate{

func transferText(name: String!) {
    workoutNameLabel.text = name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the protocol/delegate pattern backwards.

If the first VC is going to instantiate and present the second VC (the NewWorkoutVC), no "delegate" is needed in order to move data from the first VC to the second VC. At the moment you say

```
let newWorkoutVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
                       withIdentifier: "NewWorkoutVC") as! NewWorkoutVC
```

... the first VC has a reference to the second VC and can set any of its property values, right then and there, before presenting it.

(However, the first VC must not try to touch any of the second VC's *interface*. Instead, it should set a simple property value, and let the second VC pick up that property value and deal with its own interface, usually in its own `viewDidLoad`.)

So what is the delegate/protocol pattern for? That is in case the second VC will *later* need to pass info *back* to the first VC! To make that possible, the first VC will also, at the moment I was just talking about, set the *second* VC's `delegate` property to `self` (i.e. the *first* VC), so that the second VC will know how to call the first VC back. In the delegate protocol pattern:

- The **delegate property**, declared in the second VC and set as a reference to `self` by the first VC, is how the second VC knows *who* its delegate is.
- The **protocol**, defined by the second VC and adopted by the first VC, is how the second VC knows *what it can say* to its delegate.

Comment: For a working pedagogical example of communication in both directions, look at ViewController and SecondViewController in this downloadable project: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch06p264presentedViewController/ch19p601presentedViewController There is a lot of other stuff going on (the example is rather packed), but one of them is forward communication to the presented view controller and then backward communication to the presenting view controller using the delegate/protocol pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to a view controller that you are going to present, you don't use a delegate. Delegates are typically used when you want to pass data from a VC `A` to the VC that presented `A`.

Here, you can just set the property directly, since you have got the instance (`newWorkoutVC`) already:

```
let newWorkoutVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewWorkoutVC") as! NewWorkoutVC
if workoutNameTextField.text != ""{
    let workoutName = workoutNameTextField.text!
    newWorkoutVC.workoutName = workoutName
    present(newWorkoutVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

where `workoutName` is defined in `NewWorkoutVC` like this:

```
var workoutName: String!
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
    workoutNameLabel.text = workoutName
}
```